# Why doesn't Kakashi use his copy ability that often?

Tags: naruto

Kakashi is known as "the copy cat ninja". The Ninjas from the other countries call Kakashi the Copy Cat Ninja because of his Sharingan and how he uses it for his advantage (Copying moves). But he does not use his power to copy very often (or at least not anymore). It is only shown around 3-4 times that he actually copies and uses it against somebody.

Why does he not use this power more often?

Comment: He isn't a "native" Sharingan user, and using it takes a lot of chakra, so really only to be used in special cases.

Comment: @Oded indeed, But then again. he uses loads of other sharingan powers. this also deplete his chakra

Comment: Well, he is called the copy-ninja because he copied over 1000 techniques, so even though it isn't shown, he does use it a lot, no?

Comment: @Oded he is said to use it allot, But later on he issent even recognised as the copy cat ninja anymore. People just call him kakashi, And you would think if he is famous for it that he would use it more often.

Comment: @Oded: At the beginning of the series, after using it for about 30 minutes, he was unable to move for a week. But later on he showed us he can use it for longer periods, and even use the Mangekyo, without being hospitalized.

Comment: Most times, he fights against kekkai-genkai users, not? He can't copy these abilities, if I'm correct. I think there are just very few abilities that he can copy and which are worth it.

Comment: @looper meaning he only was called copy cat ninja as some sort of stepping stone to fame? As his abilty became more and more useless even other people stopped calling him copycat ?

Comment: Kakashi's only "original" technique is the Chidori / Raikiri.  That means everything else he has ever used was copied or learned.

Comment: @jw013 how often does he use anything else then fighting with kunai . chidori/raikiri  or some other special eye power? not that often

Comment: @Dimitrimx You are simply wrong.  Please go back and read the manga and count all the times Kakashi uses something that is not Chidori or Sharingan.  He has multiple water based techniques, earth based techniques for defense and stealth, clones of both shadow and lightning element, dog summons, etc.  The only reason he pulls out his Sharingan so often is it's a simple way for the author to show readers that the enemy is dangerous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What everyone was saying was partially correct. The Sharingan is a kekkei-genkai made for the Uchiha Clan. Since Kakashi isn't native to this clan, he's only able to use his Sharingan after once in awhile. As said before, he used it in the beginning of the series and was out for about a week or two from using too much chakra.

Consumption of all of your chakra will cause you to die.

Now with his Mangekyo Sharingan, he cannot use it much. The example that comes quickly to my head is when Kakashi and Naruto were chasing Deidara during the Gaara Retrieval arc. Kakashi specifically quoted that, "We have to end this soon. I can only activate the Mangekyo probably one more time."

In the current manga, he can only keep up with using his Mangekyo Sharingan with the help from the Kyuubi's aura/chakra.

**It consumes way too much chakra for him**.

Comment: So practicly you mean to say the chakra use for kakashi is way higher then for one born into the blood line. There for only with assisted chakra (kyuubi etc ) he can use it more often?

Comment: @Dimitrimx no what he says is that Kakashi from the very beginning of the manga has a very low chakra pool, he indeed stated it once (forgot the specific part) while talking to naruto about bunshins.

Answer (score 8):

All the comments are correct but the truth is that his body isn't built for Sharingan.  He uses it because it was implanted as a gift from a dying friend but there's more to Kekkai Genkai than just the gift.  It's sort of like the Hyuga clan with the Byukaggan.  If you notice there's a network of veins that support their eyes.  If their eyes were stolen it's likely this network of veins wouldn't exist in the new user and therefore might strain the user's body.

In the same way Kakashi's body isn't built for extended Sharingan use.  Sure, he can use it more than someone who had it newly implanted but he's not an Uchiha.  Where Sasuke can use it for very extended periods of time and even strain it Kakashi can not.

Comment: that kinda contradicts aswel, later on in manga if you are up to date he can keep using his eye after receiving the kyuubi chakra. making it more bound to the chakra than the veins. Although those also might have a effect

Comment: also there is someone who successfully uses a stolen byakugan, the assistant to the mizukage, Ao

Comment: I didn't know Ao stole Byakkugan successfully.  Cool.

Answer (score 3):

The answer might be even simpler than we though. Kakashi is the copy ninja, he is the one who has copied **1,000** jutsus. Why doesn't he used the copy ability of sharingan? Here's why.

1. He has copied the jutsu already, thus no need for him to copy it again.
2. The jutsu is not copy-able, such as the Hyouton Kekkei Genkai.
3. Even if he copied it, he can't use it due to not having enough chakra to perform it.
4. He can copy it but the jutsu is not worthy of being copied.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Kakashi copies techniques but not everything because only few of them are compatible. Hence he could copy 1000 techniques and not show it because there are no perfect enemy he could use his techniques on.

Answer (score -1):

You have a series where ninja use natural elements as base for techniques that can be performed to destroy villages...your only question is why Kakashi doesn't copy his opponents moves? I think, its not that significant at the moment...also to think about it, most of Kakashi opponents were Akatsuki members, who's each abilities are very unique, probably cant even be copied, apart from any element base techniques. Then again, I cannot remember if Kakashi can copy non element jutsus. Ya dig?

Comment: 1st things first. Hes known as the copy cat ninja as he already copied several hunderds of techniques  so my question is not only why doesent he copy, but also why doesent he use the moves

Comment: You know how you studied math in school...and kind of dont remember everything. Yeah, it's like that. LOL

Comment: I actually meant, further development of Kakashi at this point is not important in respect to what is going on with the Hokages, Naruto and now Sasuke...

Comment: Welcome to Anime&Manga.SE! This does not answer the question asked. Please consider editing it in order to make it an answer to the question :) Happy answering.

Comment: Then why wouldnt it be relevant. We do not know what kind of amazing techniques he has stolen from people. His copyd skills could turn about the war or safe thousands of lifes. Its not specific development for Kakashi it's more like he got a title for one of his most OP powers and its never used EVER. And if you dont remmember read it again to inform beter ;)

Answer (score -1):

I completely agree that Kakashi should have used his copy moves more. He used it like once. It has nothing to do with how the sharigan takes up chakra, because he already used the sharigan to copy base elemental justsu. So he should use the jutsus he has copied, which don't take as much chakra as his sharigan and mangekyo sharigan.

The techniques he copied from Zabuza, like water sphere, would have been very helpful in the was when dealing with few opponents.

I think it is either the legend of the copy ninja wasn't as great as we thought or the laziness of the writer.